# Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: android, flutter, apk

It gives such an error when trying to make this file apk.

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

Building without sound null safety

[!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
    To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on .
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Alp\AndroidStudioProjects\InstaUI\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > AndroidX must be enabled when Jetifier is enabled. To resolve, set android.useAndroidX=true in your gradle.properties file.
      > Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


BU�LD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            7,1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `first error` which is `AndroidX must be enabled when Jetifier is enabled. To resolve, set android.useAndroidX=true in your gradle.properties file.`

Add following two lines in `gradle.properties` file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

For your `second error`, based on your error message `Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`   you need to do the following:

Navigate to `android >> app >> build.gradle` and change your `flutter.ndkVersion` to the latest **stable** version. You can check the latest NDK stable version [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i cant find ndkVersion i have only minSkdVersion

Comment: If not, please try to add it at the location specified in screenshot above

Comment: I added it but it still didn't work

Comment: can you please post your `android/app/build.gradle` as well as your `android/build.gradle` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

[android/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSk1N.png)

[android/app/build.gradle-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UXKC.png)

[android/app/build.gradl-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmhRu.png)

Comment: Please post this as a part of the question. You can edit your question and add the code for the files. Please do not add it as answer.

Comment: And do not post pictures of code, configurations, errors etc. text in either.